# Any Java based examples to use LEADTOOLS for reading Bank Check's details?

Tags: java, leadtools-sdk, micr

Looking for Java based examples to use [LEADTOOLS](https://www.leadtools.com/) SDK for reading Bank Check's details like Account Number, MICR Code, etc. Please share if any of you have worked upon/seen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mahantesh,
LEADTOOLS has Java support on Android. There are Java demos installed with the toolkit in this folder:
[LEADTOOLS Android SDK folder]\Examples\Android
The 3 demos related to OCR are OcrDemo, MicrDemo and MinimumOCR.
The second demo in particular, MicrDemo, shows how to handle bank checks.

For other platforms such as Windows, Java isn't officially supported. However, there are ways to use the toolkit with Java such as using JNI (Java Native Interface). We have a proof-of-concept demo that shows this approach in the following page:
http://support.leadtools.com/SupportPortal/CS/forums/26876/ShowPost.aspx
If the approach itself works for your case, you can modify the project to support OCR and MICR. You should keep in mind that the code will not be identical among different platforms, but the semantics and logic will have many similarities.

Answer (score 0):

There's new information about this:

LEAD recently released a setup of LEADTOOLS 19 that includes Java APIs for Windows and Linux. Since you want to recognize regular text (Account Number) and bank checks MICR code, you can use LEADTOOLS OCR and MICR features.

After installing the new setup, you can find the Java OCR demo's source code here:
[LEADTOOLS 19 folder]\Examples\Java\OcrDemo
For regular text, set the zone's type to OcrZoneType.Text and for the MICR special code, modify the demo and change the type of the zone that contains your MICR symbol to OcrZoneType.MICR before running OCR.
The MICR zone's code will be something as follows:

```
OcrZone ocrZone = new OcrZone();
// Set ocrZone's bound
ocrZone.setBounds(demoData.zoneBounds);
ocrZone.setZoneType(OcrZoneType.MICR);
```